# Why does onclick not work on a button but works on a DIV in Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, button

I've decided to dabble in writing a Google Chrome extension. I'm looking through the samples and writing my own versions. I've downloaded [set_page_color](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/browserAction/set_page_color/) and I'm writing my own version of it.

Can someone tell me why this doesn't work

```
<button onclick="click(this)" id="red">Red</button>
```

when this does

```
<div onclick="click(this)" id="red">Red</div>
```

I'm happy to use a div if I must but I don't see why I need to. Especially since the [Google Analytics tutorial](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/tut_analytics.html#toc-tracking-events) uses buttons for their javascript triggers.

If you need more code let me know.

**Edit**

Here is the code from google's set_page_color popup.html (bits are missing that I'm sure aren't relevant)

```
<script>
function click(color) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
        {code:"document.body.style.backgroundColor='" + color.id + "'"});
    window.close();
}
</script>
<div onclick="click(this)" id="red">red</div>
<div onclick="click(this)" id="blue">blue</div>
<div onclick="click(this)" id="green">green</div>
<div onclick="click(this)" id="yellow">yellow</div>
```

Here's their manifest file

```
{
    "name": "A browser action with a popup that changes the page color.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Set this page's color.",
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

That's all there is to it. If you change the `<div onclick= ...` to `<button onclick=...` it doesn't work.

Comment: I think "click" is a reserved word. <div onclick="alert('hello')" id="red">Red</div> should work.

Comment: I would imagine this is a nuance of your particular extension. This should definitely work in general. We nay need much more context to be able to help you.

Comment: @Diodeus It _does_ work in a `<div>` it _doesn't_ work in a `button`. According to MDN `click` isn't a reserved keyword. I like your thinking though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `click` is a property on `<button>` DOM elements, but not on `<a>` DOM elements. Rename your method and it should work just fine.

Comment: Excellent, that must be it. Changing the method name does indeed make it work as expected. Thank you!

Comment: @MrMisterMan: why would you ever call a function `click` in an `onclick`, unless your function assumes control of the mouse and clicks, that is poor programming.

Comment: It's not the OP's fault. The code is actually directly from the `set_page_color` sample.

Comment: @vol7ron I don't imagine I would ever call a function click if I was writing it myself.